# Get searched results of vuetify's v-autocomplete

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

See this codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNOGmY?editors=1010

```
// HTML
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline font-weight-regular blue-grey white--text">Profile</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        {{ searchedItems }}
        <v-subheader class="pa-0">Where do you live?</v-subheader>
        <v-autocomplete
          v-model="model"
          :items="states"
          :label="State"
          :search-input.sync="filter"
          ref="selectExample"
        >
        </v-autocomplete>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
// JS
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      model: null,
      filter: '',
      searchedItems: [],
      states: [
        'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona',
        'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut',
        'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Federated States of Micronesia',
        'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho',
        'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
        'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland',
        'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi',
        'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada',
        'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York',
        'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio',
        'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico',
        'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee',
        'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Island', 'Virginia',
        'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
      ]
    }
  },
  watch:{
    filter(newVal){
      // I want to get the filtered items list here
      this.searchedItems = this.$refs['selectExample'].items
    }
  }
})
```

My use case is that when user types in the autocomplete input box, the list of items gets filtered in the dropdown list and I want to use that filtered items.

Vuetify's docs does not mention any prop that exposes this filtered list. Does anyone know how I can get that list in my code?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

VAutocomplete stores it in [`filteredItems`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete/VAutocomplete.js#L85) property.

You used ref `<v-autocomplete ref="selectExample"` so then you can access it like so:

```
this.$refs.selectExample.filteredItems
```

Here is the working playground. It's better to check it in full-page mode.

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      model: null,
      filter: '',
      searchedItems: [],
      states: [
        'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona',
        'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut',
        'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Federated States of Micronesia',
        'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho',
        'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
        'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland',
        'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi',
        'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada',
        'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York',
        'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio',
        'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico',
        'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee',
        'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Island', 'Virginia',
        'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
      ]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    filter() {
      this.searchedItems = this.$refs['selectExample']?.filteredItems
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app { line-height: 3; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="headline font-weight-regular blue-grey white--text">Profile</v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      searchedItems: {{ searchedItems }}
      <v-subheader class="pa-0">Where do you live?</v-subheader>
      <v-autocomplete
        v-model="model"
        :items="states"
        label="State"
        :search-input.sync="filter"
        ref="selectExample"
      >
      </v-autocomplete>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```